# Can I embed styles and javascript in blade component (template)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Just like a Vue component, you write your styles and js in the component it self.
I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in Laravel blade.

So what I'm looking for is a library that can extract the styles and js from all the blade templates, apply the Pre-Processors and Post CSS things, output a bundled js and css file.

Comment: I haven't heard of one, but a related concept is purgeCss, where it will strip down your css files based on what classes are actually being used in your project. See https://github.com/spatie/laravel-mix-purgecss